# how do you sort date fields with Rogue?

Tags: mongodb, scala, lift

```
  object trade_date extends LocalDateField(this) {
    override def displayName = "Trade Date"

  }
```

-

```
  def findAllSortByDateThisGivesAnError: List[Trade] = Trade
    .orderAsc(_.trade_date)
    .fetch()
```

no workie - here is the error message

```
[error] /home/neil/Workspace2/acm-web/src/main/scala/code/model/Trade.scala:98:
could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type com.foursquare.rogue.BSONType[java.util.Calendar]

[error] /home/neil/Workspace2/acm-web/src/main/scala/code/model/Trade.scala:98: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type com.foursquare.rogue.BSONType[java.util.Calendar]
[error]     .orderAsc(_.trade_date)
[error]                 ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Jun 14, 2013 9:33:15 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

Rogue doesn't support `Calendar` fields very well. If you can, use `DateField` or `DateTimeField`, which are backed by `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much THE answer as a pointer to anyone wrestling with Rogue and dates - when something doesn't work, make it a DateTime and pass it in to Rogue; when it comes back, you'll likely have to drag it out of java.util.Date and back into Joda.

```
object begins extends DateField(this) {
    override def displayName = "Begins"
}
```

That DateField sorts.